# Create link to PayPal payment page using payment ID

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am setting up a management panel on an ecommerce site and I would like to be able to click a link to go to each individual payment using its payment ID. This is simple using stripe:

https://dashboard.stripe.com/payments/CHARGE-ID-HERE

Is there an equivalent for PayPal?